# Fatal error in VS using Xamarin for Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

[image: A photo of the error in my output window.]

The app crashes and shuts down. I saw that part of the error was android-22 so I removed my Google Play Services component which was version 25 but it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

I was building at the wrong level for my device (i.e. level 22), changed the API Level and we're away laughing